# Check for new month and execute sub in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date

The flow of my program is the following.

On form load, the program will check current date. If it is in a new month, some function is called.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Oh. Sorry, the program is VB.NET

Comment: What do you mean by 'new month'? Does it mean you want to store date of previous run, or just check if it is the first day of month?

Comment: Just check it. That's it. Let's say, today's date is 24/8/2011. When it reaches 1/9/2011, it will execute a function.

Comment: That's not just checking. This is two completely different scenario. Let's say you application run at 24/8/2011. And the nex time it runs is 3/9/2011. Should the function be called? Or you are absolutely sure your application is called every day?

Comment: What if you don't run it on 1/9/2011? What if it doesn't run until 2/9/2011 (say, something went wrong that day)?  How will it know?

Comment: John >> Sorry for misunderstanding. Yes, it will run the function when it reached the date.

Comment: Joel>> That's only an example, that is why I am asking when it reached new month. It means whenever I run the program in any date around that new month. It does not mean I have to run it only on the first day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you save the date of the previous run of your software, you could have code smilar to this:

```
'Get the date of the previous run, that you could have saved in the database    
Dim previousDate = GetDateOfPreviousRun()

Dim currentDate = DateTime.Today()

If currentDate.Month > previousDate.Month OrElse currentDate.Year > previousDate.Year Then
    SomeFunctionIsCalled()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code give me an idea.